# Select a random element from a list based on inverse weight

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of weighted elements, and I want to select an element with a probability **inversely** proportional to its weight.

For example, in a list `[a, b, c]` with weights `[4, 3, 2]` respectively, I could eliminate elements using weighted probabilities until I have a list of 1 element, which is the chosen element. In this algorithm, in the first iteration, element `a` would be eliminated with probability `4/9`. If `a` is eliminated in the first round, we have an array `[b, c]` with weights `[3, 2]`. From there, element `b` would be eliminated with probability `3/5`. If `b` is eliminated, we have chosen the element `c`.

In the case with 3 elements, the probability that `c` is selected is the probability that both `a` and `b` are eliminated. This is the same as the probability that `a` then `b` is eliminated plus the probability that `b` then `a` is eliminated or

```
(
    // a eliminated first
    w(a) / (w(a) + w(b) + w(c)) *
    // b eliminated second
    w(b) / (w(b) + w(c))
) +
(
    // b eliminated first
    w(b) / (w(a) + w(b) + w(c)) *
    // a eliminated second
    w(a) / (w(a) + w(c))
)
```

Is there a way to quickly calculate the probability of each individual element regardless of the number of elements in the list and confirm that the probabilities sum to 1? Or is there a separate algorithm that can be used to chose an element inversely proportional to its weight?

Comment: Why not change your weights from `[4, 3, 2]` to `[1/4, 1/3, 1/2]`, then normalize (divide each by the sum of the array), then sample normally from the resulting probability distribution (e.g., `numpy.random.choice([a, b, c], p=probs)`)?

Comment: @pkpnd so the weights would become `[((1/4) / (1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2)), ((1/3) / (1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2), ((1/2) / (1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2))]`? That seems reasonable. I can make that the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sample with probability inversely proportional to some weights, you can equivalently sample with probability proportional to the inverse of those weights. So we first invert all weights, normalize the weights such that they sum to 1 (to form a probability distribution), and then sample from this distribution normally.

Here's some Python-esque pseudocode:

```
weights = [1.0 / w for w in weights]           # Invert all weights
sum_weights = sum(weights)
weights = [w / sum_weights for w in weights]   # Normalize weights
return numpy.random.choice(options, p=weights) # Sample
```

Or in numpy:

```
weights = numpy.reciprocal(weights)            # Invert all weights
weights = weights / numpy.sum(weights)         # Normalize
return numpy.random.choice(options, p=weights) # Sample
```